# R box plot with all data points ordered from low to high

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

In R, I would like to create a box plot that also shows all data points. There are numerous posts and websites where you can find this information, but they all seem to show the data points in ‘jitter’ or ‘random’ style. Here is an example code using the ToothGrowth dataset with ggplot2 in R.

```
library(datasets)
data(ToothGrowth)
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + 
  geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE) +
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.2))
```

However, I would like to have the data points ordered from the lowest at the lower-left to highest at the top-right. Please see example in this link:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3966983/figure/F1/ (freely accessible). Specifically, I refer to Figure 1a, top portion (‘Purity’).

Might anyone have suggestions? I would much appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are after but maybe you can inspire yourself from the code below.

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 20
x <- rnorm(n)

boxplot(x)
points(seq(0.75, 1.25, length.out = n), sort(x))
```

[image]

```
df1 <- sapply(1:4, function(i) rnorm(n, mean = i))
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
df1 <- reshape2::melt(df1)

boxplot(value ~ variable, df1)
sp <- split(df1, df1$variable)
for(i in 1:4){
  points(seq(i - 0.25, i + 0.25, length.out = n), sort(sp[[i]]$value))
}
```

[image]

**Edit.**

A `ggplot2` solution uses a similar trick to define the points' x axis coordinates. The only thing *"strange"*, is to rely on R's internal representation of factors as consecutive integers starting at 1. Note that this must be seen as a hack, but as a reliable one, I don't believe it will ever change.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  arrange(value) %>%
  mutate(xcoord = seq(-0.25, 0.25, length.out = n())) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value, group = variable)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = xcoord + as.integer(variable)))
```

[image]

Comment: If you change the point type to `pch=20` the results are closer to the referenced example.

Comment: Thanks @rui-barradas and R. Schifini. I am new on here, so had to edit my original question and in the meantime you guys already answered. Superb! However, any chance you could do this using ggplot2 too, please? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again @rui-barradas. That's terrific! I added a follow-up question above, if you are able to help. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @PeterDuncan, if you are satisfied with this answer, please, consider to accept it by clicking on the check mark. This will help other users of SO as well as granting additional  reputation points to the answerer. For further guidance, please, see the [SO Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you.